# How to display the rating of the current post in the WordPress loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a post type the posts of this post type are displayed with this code:

```
<?php
   $args = array (
   'post_type' => 'brands',
   'posts_per_page' => -1
   );
 $brands = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php while ( $brands->have_posts() ) :  $brands->the_post(); ?> 

 <p class="name"><?php the_title(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

Near the title, I need to display the rating of this post. To do this, inside the loop, I write this code:

```
 <?php 
    $comments = get_approved_comments( $post_id );
    foreach( $comments as $comment ){
       $rate = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true );
       if( isset( $rate ) && '' !== $rate ) {
       $i++;
       $total += $rate;
       $avrating = round($total / $i, 1);
      }
    }
 ?>

 <?php
    global $post;
    $stars   = '';
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $avrating + 1; $i++ ) {
    $width = intval( $i - $avrating > 0 ? 20 - ( ( $i - $avrating ) * 20 ) : 20 );
    if ( 0 === $width ) {
       continue;
    }
    $stars .= '<span style="overflow:hidden; width:' . $width . 'px" class="dashicons dashicons-star-filled"></span>';
     if ( $i - $avrating > 0 ) {
    $stars .= '<span style="overflow:hidden; position:relative; left:-' . $width .'px;" class="dashicons dashicons-star-empty"></span>'; 
    }
    }
    echo $stars;
```

?>

But as a result, I get the same values for all posts.  And I need to get different values corresponding to the post, if any, and display nothing if there is no rating. Help please, I myself cannot solve this issue.

Comment: You're not showing where $post_id comes from, so we can't answer your question with 100% confidence. I see a few areas where things could go wrong, but my best guess is that $post_id comes from outside the loop and refers to the single, outer Post.

Comment: If this is truly within the loop, you don't need to call `global $post` and as @mattavatar pointed out, `$post_id` isn't set anywhere, but you could use `$post->ID`

Comment: Thanks, guys, but I found a solution. It may not be very elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. There may be better options, but right now my code works and solves my needs. All I've done is to place test before the code that prints rating:

```
<?php $comments = get_approved_comments( $post_id ); ?>
   <?php if($comments == true): ?>
 

   <?php endif; ?>
```

As a result, we first check to see if the post has confirmed the comments. If there is, then there is a rating (in my case, a comment cannot be left unrated). If there are more elegant solutions I'll be glad to see.